# Do covalent bonds fit in with the orbital theory of atomic structure?

Tags: bond, electronic-configuration

Which atomic model do covalent bonds adhere to?

In the the covalent bond between $2$ oxygen atoms, we consider each oxygen atom to have $6$ valence electrons, thus resulting in a double covalent bond.

However, the electronic configuration as per the orbital theory is $\mathrm{1s^2 2s^2 2p^4}$, i.e. $4$ valence electrons. In such a case, how can an oxygen atom bond with another atom to form $\ce{O2}$?

I feel there is something simple that I haven't understood yet that explains this.

Comment: For compounds one does not use atomic orbitals, one uses *molecular* orbitals.

Answer (score 0):

The total number of valence electrons does not determine the structure of the molecule $\ce{O2}$. The number of non paired electrons is more important. The Oxygen atom has $4$ electrons $2p$, but $2$ of these $4$ electrons are paired, and so are unavailable to make a bond. It remains $4 - 2 = 2$ free and unpaired $2p$ electrons (unpaired electrons are indicated as points in the Lewis model). These $2$ electrons can produce a valence bond. In the Lewis model, the oxygen atom may be drawn |O:, with one more bar under the O atom (Sorry : I am unable to underline). If two such Oxygen atoms are in contact, the $2$ free electrons from each atoms are producing $2$ valence bonds between them, like in the formula |O=O| (with underlined bar under each O). And this gives each atom a configuration respecting the octet rule.

Comment: That is a bit confusing. There are bonds, which we call dative or coordinate bonds, in which the electrons come from one partner. In the end all Valence electrons will be in molecular orbitals, no matter of whether they were paired before or not.

Comment: Covalent bonds may be dative or not. They are always made of paired electrons, also called doublets

Comment: I find it very odd that you chose dioxygen as an example in your answer, as it is proof that the statement you just made is completely wrong. Even the simplest molecule, with which thousands of people started to learn about quantum chemistry only has one electron.

Comment: @Martin. You are absolutely right. The example of $\ce{O2}$ is specially poor. Because $\ce{O2}$ is a rather special case. It has no double bond at all. It is a diradical. I was only trying to answer the initial question asked by Aditi, about the nature of the covalence. But you are right. it would have been much better to choose another molecule, like $\ce{H2O}$ or $\ce{CO2}$